# Validar campo telefónico con jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap, regex, validación

Tengo problemas con mi script en *jQuery*. Funciona con el `input` de correo pero con el de celular no funciona.

```js
$('#validate').click(function() {

  var regex = /[\w-\.]{2,}@([\w-]{2,}\.)*([\w-]{2,}\.)[\w-]{2,4}/;

  if (regex.test($('#correo').val().trim())) {

  } else {
    alert('La direccón de correo no es válida');
  }

  if (isNaN($('#cel').val())) {
    alert('El teléfono solo debe contener números');
  }
  if ($('#cel').val().length < 9) {
    alert('El teléfono debe tener 9 caracteres. Ej. 666112233');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row justify-content-center mt-4">
      <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="input-group flex-nowrap">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping"><i class="fa fa-phone-square bigicon"></i></span>
          </div>
          <input type="cel" id="cel" class="form-control" name="cel" placeholder="Celular">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: El input type "cel" no existe, tiene que ser type "tel"

Comment: hice el cambio pero no funciono

Comment: Exception: DOMException: Failed to execute 'matches' on 'Element': '[s!='']:x' is not a valid selector. at https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2:11289 at se (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2:7235) at oe.setDocument (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2:11238) at https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2:22668 at https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2:23383 at https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2:220 at https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2:225
e: fieldset
this: undefined
Closure

Comment: Pues utilizando lo que nos enseñas, a mi me funciona perfectamente, en cuanto el error ese que pones, no parece que tenga que ver con el codigo mostrado

Answer (score 1):

Este es un ejemplo funcional de validación para un campo telefónico con `jQuery`.

```js
 
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#formulario").submit(function () {
  if($("#telefono").val().length < 1) {
   alert("El teléfono es obligatorio");
   return false;
  }
  if(isNaN($("#telefono").val())) {
   alert("El teléfono solo debe contener números");
   return false;
  }
  if($("#telefono").val().length < 10) {
   alert("El teléfono debe tener 10 caracteres. Ej. 3214568526");
   return false;
  }
  return false;
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="formulario" id="formulario" action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="telefono" id="telefono">
<input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

otra opcion si solo quieres habilitar el boton cuando el formato es correcto,
en lugar de habilitar el boton puedes indicar al usuario que el formato es correcto sin necesidad de esperar hasta presionar enviar.

```js
var i = document.getElementById("phone"),
    b = document.getElementById("formatBtn"),
    f = document.getElementById("field"),
    regex = i.pattern; //patron declarado en el control 

//el boton se habilita cuando el numero es correcto
i.addEventListener("input", function(e){
    b.disabled = true;  
    var n = i.value;  
    if (n.match(regex)) {
        b.disabled = false;
    }
}, false);
```

```css
* When the pattern is matched */
input[type="tel"]:valid {
    color: green;
}

input[type="tel"]:valid ~  label::after {
    content: " ✓ ";
    color: green;
}

/* Unmatched */
input[type="tel"]:invalid {
    color: red;
}
  

/* */
input, button, #field {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: .3em;
    border-radius: 1em;
    margin: .2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label >Escriba su numero telefonico (10 digitos)</label>
  <div class="form-group">
<input type="tel" id="phone" value="" 
    placeholder="5514260834" 
    pattern="\d{10}"
    required
/>
<label for="phone"></label>
   </div>
</br>
<button id="formatBtn" disabled>Enviar Forma</button>
```